# FindNext in vba not moving on

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba script that goes over a set of data just like the one below.  It picks out the user name, in this case "Administrator" and then goes over to another spreadsheet and searches for that user name.  Once it finds it, it comes back to the  other spreadsheet and goes down one cell, and searches for the text within that cell in the other spreadsheet.  In the cell that intersects the column (containing the user name) and the row (containing the other set of data) it marks an "X".  It then loops over this set of data, doing this for each piece of data under that user name.  Then it moves onto the next set of data, which is in the same format, and does the same process all over again.  Or at least it is supposed to.  Everything about this script works except after it gets to the bottom of the first set of data, which is an empty cell, it doesn't set the range right to find the next match.  For some reason the `FindNext` call finds "Users,Builtin" which is the last piece of data in the first set.  I am really confused as  to why this is happening.  I have a feeling it might have to do with how I am using the `ActiveCell` but I am really not sure.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Script:

```
Sub AssignGroups()

    Dim membership As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim groups As Worksheet
    Dim nameRow As Long
    Dim fullNameString As String
    Dim nameRange As Range
    Dim groupRange As Range
    Dim nameRange2 As Range
    Dim nameIndex As Long
    Dim userNameString As String
    Dim barIndex As Long



    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set membership = Sheets("User Group Membership")
    Set groups = Sheets("User Assigned to Groups")
    Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find("user -name", LookAt:=xlPart)


    If Not nameRange Is Nothing Then

        firstAddress = nameRange.Address

    Do

    membership.Activate
    nameRow = nameRange.Row
    MsgBox (nameRow)
    fullNameString = membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Value
    'MsgBox (fullNameString)
    nameIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "user -name")
    barIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "|")
    'MsgBox (nameIndex)
    'MsgBox (barIndex)
    userNameString = Mid(fullNameString, nameIndex + 12, ((barIndex - 4) - (nameIndex + 12)))

    groups.Activate
    Set nameRange2 = groups.Range("A:CH").Find(userNameString)
    nameColumn = nameRange2.Column



    membership.Activate
    membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Activate

    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate

        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

            cellValue = ActiveCell.Value
            groups.Activate
            Set groupRange = groups.Range("A:CH").Find(cellValue, , , LookAt:=xlWhole)
            groupRow = groupRange.Row
            groups.Cells(groupRow, nameColumn).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "X"
            membership.Activate

         End If



        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

    Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").FindNext(nameRange)
    MsgBox (nameRange.Address)

    Loop While Not nameRange Is Nothing Or nameRange.Address <> firstAddress
    End If


End Sub
```

Data:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.CHESCONETAD>dsquery user -name "Administrator"   | dsget user -memberof -expand 
Administrators,Builtin
Domain Admins,Users
Domain Users,Users
EMLibrary Users,Users
Enterprise Admins,Users
Exchange Organization Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups
Exchange Public Folder Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups
Exchange Recipient Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups
Exchange View-Only Administrators,OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups
Group Policy Creator Owners,Users
Schema Admins,Users
SophosAdministrator,Users
Users,Builtin
```

Comment: Why a find for `A:CH` then a second find for `A:A`? Combine the two?

Comment: Because one is on the groups sheet and the other is on the membership sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your suspicion that 'ActiveCell`is causing your problems. It's best to avoid`ActiveCell`and`Activate`and`Select` statements, unless you **absolutely** need them. It's better to work directly with the objects.

I think if you place the `Until` statement next to the `Do` in the second `Do Loop` instead of next to the `Loop` it will work better as well.

Lastly, because you are using multiple finds in the code the `FindNext` command is using the last thing you entered in the `Find` dialogue, so you need to adjust that statement as well to do exactly what you want.

See the code I refactored below and let me know if it does not solve the problem. Notice how I qualified all the variables, changed the `Until` placement in the second loop, and adjust the `.FindNext` line.

```
Sub AssignGroups()

    Dim membership As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim groups As Worksheet
    Dim nameRow As Long
    Dim fullNameString As String
    Dim nameRange As Range
    Dim groupRange As Range
    Dim nameRange2 As Range
    Dim nameIndex As Long
    Dim userNameString As String
    Dim barIndex As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set membership = Sheets("User Group Membership")
    Set groups = Sheets("User Assigned to Groups")


    With membership

        Set nameRange = .Range("A:A").Find("user -name", LookAt:=xlPart)


        If Not nameRange Is Nothing Then

            firstAddress = nameRange.Address

            Do

                nameRow = nameRange.Row

                'MsgBox (nameRow)

                fullNameString = .Cells(nameRow, "A").Value

                'MsgBox (fullNameString)

                nameIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "user -name")
                barIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "|")

                'MsgBox (nameIndex)
                'MsgBox (barIndex)

                userNameString = Mid(fullNameString, nameIndex + 12, ((barIndex - 4) - (nameIndex + 12)))

            With groups

                Set nameRange2 = .Range("A:CH").Find(userNameString)
                nameColumn = nameRange2.Column

            End With


            Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(nameRow, "A").Offset(1))

                cellValue = .Cells(nameRow, "A").Offset(1)

                With groups

                    Set groupRange = .Range("A:CH").Find(cellValue, , , LookAt:=xlWhole)

                    groupRow = groupRange.Row
                    .Cells(groupRow, nameColumn).Value = "X"

                End With

                nameRow = nameRow + 1

            Loop

            Set nameRange = .Range("A:A").Find("user -name", After:=nameRange, LookAt:=xlPart)

        MsgBox (nameRange.Address)

        Loop While Not nameRange Is Nothing Or nameRange.Address <> firstAddress

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  For some reason it is still not moving onto the next set of data.  At the end of the loop, `nameRange` is still getting set to `Users,Builtin` just like before.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: That worked! One more thing though, it doesn't seem to be breaking from the big loop once it is done processing all the data.  Is it possible that setting `nameRange` at the bottom of the loop like we did would mess up the address when the Loop checks the conditional?

Comment: hmmm - seems like that would work. Can you debug it and see what happens when it gets to the last data set and goes to `set nameRange = .Range("A:A").Find("user -name" ...` at the end. What happens after it sets that again. What range does it find after the last one is finished? That will tell you why it keeps looping and you (or I) can adjust the code based on that.